# as: unrecognized option '-meabi=5' due to incomplete pack of cross-compiler?

Tags: sockets, gcc, openembedded

The workbench OS is Ubuntu12.04 x64.

#### Build cross-compiler.

`mkdir app_devkit; cd app_devkit
repo init -u git://codeaurora.org/quic/le/manifest.git -b release -m LNX.LE.5.1-66056-9x40.xm
repo sync
cd oe-core; . build/conf/set_bb_env.sh
bitbake gcc`

#### Test cross-compiler --> OK.

`tmp-eglibc/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/armv7a-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o hello_world hello_world.c`

#### Pack with some 'socket ignored'

`cd ../../..
tar zcf app_devkit.tgz app_devkit
tar: app_devkit/oe-core/build/tmp-eglibc/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/3.8-r0/pseudo/pseudo.socket: socket ignored
...
tar: app_devkit/oe-core/build/tmp-eglibc/sysroots/x86_64-linux/var/pseudo/pseudo.socket: socket ignored`

#### Unpack and test again --> NG

`cd <somewhere else>
tar zxf <path to app_devkit.tgz>
cd app_devkit/oe-core/build
tmp-eglibc/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/armv7a-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o hello_world hello_world.c
as: unrecognized option '-meabi=5'`

Answer (score 0):

The toolchain deployed under `tmp-eglibc/sysroot/...` is not intended to directly be moved.

Instead do either of the following:

1. Run `bitbake meta-toolchain` to create a generic toolchain.
2. Run `bitbake -c populate_sdk <image-name>`, where you replace `<image-name>` with the name of the image you're using.

The first will create a generic toolchain, while the latter will ensure that the sysroot in the toolchain matches your image.

In both cases, the toolchain will be found in `tmp-eglic/deploy/sdk/`, as a `.sh`-file. Just execute this file, and tell it where you want your toolchain to be installed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  What do you mean by a "generic" toolchain ?   How to find possible <image-name> ?   Itried "bitbake -c populate_sdk app_devkit" and result is "ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'app_devkit'"

Comment: A generic sdk doesn't contain you image's sysroot. Thus, you won't get all the header files and libraries that can be found in your image. Regarding your failed attempt to create a image-based sdk; what's the name of the image that should be built? Check the doc's for your layer / vendor in question, order to see if they've documented this. Images are normally found under `layer/recipes-*/images/XXX.bb`. You could also try the generic SDK.

Comment: Thanks Anders.  Invoking the resulting meta-toolchain/../arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-gcc returns "No such file or directory".  It is a "ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.16".  The workbench PC is a "Linux 3.2.0-88-generic #126-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 6 21:33:03 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux".  Does this imply meta-toolchain is not supported by this distribution ?   I will try populate_sdk.

Comment: meta-toolchain should work, it's a party of the image based toolchain. (This, of our doesn't work  the latter won't work either). Have you installed the toolchain? If not, execute the sh-file add indicated in my response. After that, source the environment-file in the install location. Then you can call $CC directly.

Comment: Thanks Anders.  When installing SDK, some "ERROR: could not relocate ***, interp size = 78 and 90 is needed." show and finally "SDK has been successfully set up and is ready to be used".
Whether environment-setup-armv7a-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi is sourced or not, invoking arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-gcc returns "No such file or directory".

Comment: Well, if it fails to relocate, that might very well expain the behaviour. Just to note, you should always source the environment-file, prior to calling $CC. I'd double check that the path and linker path is correct in the environment file. (It sounds as your cross-compiler can't find a linked library).

Apart from that, you could try the oe-core mailinglist, though the version used is __really__ old; I'd definitely approach the vendor to get a more up-to-date version.